# difference between .text and .code section name

Tags: assembly, disassembly

I work with pe files analyzer sofwares like exeinfoPe and in section list part there are both .text and CODE section types that we can use them for example change .data name to .text or CODE or other section names. are these section typesthe same? what is difference between them?

Comment: Please see [code segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) and [data segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment). Sometimes, they can be the same.

Comment: I believe you are talking about section names, not flags. There are some common section names, but they are not required. What count are in fact the flags (such as executable or writable).

Comment: yes I was wrong. thanks for your your answer and reminding. I correct the question. @Jester

Comment: `.code` and `.text` segments are synonymous. Otherwise segments are usually not interchangeable. For example, those are read-only on many architectures.

Comment: You've confused section names with section flags.  `CODE` is a section flag and `.text` a section name.  While the name of a section gives a pretty good clue what its used for, a section can be named anything and it's the section flags that determine what it can be used for.

Comment: @RossRidge I don't think so. In PE Explorer section software and in section editor part there is a section type changing option that has a list of section types like .data .text .rsrc and also CODE so I think CODE is a section type that PE Explorer suggest it for using!!

Comment: PE Explorer has mislead you. While `CODE`, specifically `IMAGE_SCN_CNT_CODE`, is a section flag that could, in combination with other flags, or absence of other flags, be considered to denote the type of a section, `.text` is just section name. By convention it has the flags `IMAGE_SCN_CNT_CODE|IMAGE_SCN_MEM_EXECUTE|IMAGE_SCN_MEM_READ` but sections with different names can also have this "type", and a section named `.text` can, at least in theory, have other flags. See the PECOFF spec for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680547(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no functional difference between the `.text` and `.code` sections of a binary.

In almost all cases, they are completely synonymous (meaning that they refer to the same section), but even when they're not (*e.g.* due to the actual order of sections in the binary), they are *semantically* identical.

This is the section of the object file or address space that contains executable instructions ("code"), which are stored as plain text ("text"). It is almost always read-only, unlike the `.data` section.

Consult the documentation for your assembler, compiler, linker, or disassembler to see which name it prefers. The PE format uses `.text`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no semantic difference between the `.CODE` and `.TEXT` sections.
Just as in the `MASM` assembler, the instruction space address is named by `.CODE` section, and in other compilers is named by `.CODE`.

So when you assemble your code with `MASM` you will see `.CODE` section as well as `.TEXT`.